# Powershell script to create a meeting in outlook

Tags: powershell, outlook

I am trying to create a `PowerShell` script to create a meeting in the Outlook. I am stuck in the code for setting up the timezone of the meeting. The time zones I am looking for is `CST`, `PST`, `EST`, `AEST`.

```
$Outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
$OutlookFolders = $Outlook.Session.Folders.Item(1).Folders
$tzs = $Outlook.TimeZones
$NewEvent = $Outlook.CreateItem(1)
$NewEvent.Subject = "Meeting";
$NewEvent.Start = [datetime]”6/13/2019 19:00"
$NewEvent.End = [datetime]"6/13/2019 20:00"
$NewEvent.StartTimeZone =$tzs.CurrentTimeZone.Name("Central Standard 
Time")
$NewEvent.EndTimeZone = $tzs.CurrentTimeZone.Name("Central Standard 
Time")
$NewEvent.SendUsingAccount = 'name@abc.com'
$NewEvent.Recipients('name@abc.com')
$NewEvent.save()
```

Error I am getting for above code is listed below

> Cannot find an overload for "ID" and the argument count: "1" At
>   C:\Powershell\outlook-base.ps1:12 char:5 + $NewEvent.StartTimeZone =
>   $Outlook.TimeZones.CurrentTimeZone.ID(" ... +  CategoryInfo :
>   NotSpecified: (:) [], GetValueInvocationException +
>   FullyQualifiedErrorId : RuntimeException Cannot find an overload for
>   "ID" and the argument count: "1" At C:\Powershell\outlook-base.ps1:13
>   char:5 + $NewEvent.EndTimeZone =
>   $Outlook.TimeZones.CurrentTimeZone.ID("Ce ... +  CategoryInfo :
>   NotSpecified: (:) [], GetValueInvocationException +
>   FullyQualifiedErrorId : RuntimeException

Answer (score 3):

Update line 8 and 9 with this:

```
$NewEvent.StartTimeZone =$tzs["Central Standard Time"]
$NewEvent.EndTimeZone = $tzs["Central Standard Time"]
```

Comment: After updating those 2 lines, below error appeared
Cannot index into a null array.
At C:\Powershell\testerror.ps1:29 char:5
+     $NewEvent.StartTimeZone =$tzs["Central Standard Time"]
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray
 
Cannot index into a null array.
At C:\Powershell\testerror.ps1:30 char:5
+     $NewEvent.EndTimeZone = $tzs["Central Standard Time"]
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray